# How to configure a SiteMapPath control for breadcrumbs? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

I have added a site map path control to a master page and set up the sitemap file as required, but when I click on multiple links it only shows the current and the home page eg, path`Home --> Movies` where as it should be Home --> Movies --> Clothes --> etc.. Also when I go to the cust sign up and administration pages the path doesn't how at all.

Can someone explain how to fix this problem as I can't see where I have gone wrong with implementing it?

The sitemap:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description="Main site page">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Movies.aspx" title="Movies"  description="Movie store" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Games.aspx" title="Games"  description="Games store" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Clothes.aspx" title="Clothes"  description="Clothes Store" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/CustomerSignUp.aspx" title="Customer Sign-Up"  description="Customer sign up page" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Login.aspx" title="Sign-In"  description="Sign In page" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/ForgotPassword.aspx" title="Forgot Password"  description="Forgot password" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/ContactUs.aspx" title="Contact Us"  description="Contact details.." />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Administration.aspx" title="Administration"  description="Admin Folder" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

[image: site path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap up child sitemapnodes in parent sitemapnode,

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description="Main site page">
       <siteMapNode url="~/Movies.aspx" title="Movies"  description="Movie store">
           <siteMapNode url="~/Clothes.aspx" title="Clothes"  description="Clothes Store" />
       </siteMapNode>   
</siteMapNode>
```

For further understanding, refer [this article](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/sitemap-navigation-control-example-in.html).

Comment: Can you please give me some assistance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892575/how-to-set-up-a-breadcrumb-in-an-asp-net-page Thanks.